# Ruby convert Array to Fixnum

Tags: ruby

I failed to find anything relevant when I was researching it. I am bascially trying to convert an array, for example `[5, 1, 7 ,8]` to a fixnum which will have the value of `5178`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[5, 1, 7 ,8].inject{|n, d| n * 10 + d}
# => 5178
```

Comparison

```
t = Time.now
100000.times do
  [5, 1, 7 ,8].inject{|n, d| n * 10 + d}
end
Time.now - t # => 0.108719628

t = Time.now
100000.times do
  [5, 1, 7, 8].join.to_i
end
Time.now - t # => 0.246565502
```

Comment: Because it does not generate intermediate strings. It does calculation directly within numerals. In my view, it is much more straightforward to calculate decimal digits following its definition rather than converting the digits once to a string and then parsing it as a number.

Comment: @sawa one small modification I would like to suggest for using .inject(0), it increases readability for starting result value.
[5, 1, 7 ,8].inject(0){|n, d| n * 10 + d}

Comment: @sawa we can use benchmark too to compare, you might be knowing it for sure, even though have a look kindly here please

require 'benchmark'
arr = [5,1,7,8]
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { arr.join.to_i }
  x.report { arr.inject(0){|result, ele_val| result * 10 + ele_val} }
end

user     system      total        real
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000015)
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000009)

Comment: I've upvoted even though there is a comma out of place in the first line.

Answer (score 10):

Do as below:

```
 => [5, 1, 7 ,8].join.to_f
 => # 5178.0
```

This too work:

```
 => [1,2,3,4].join.to_i
 => # 1234
```

Comment: Oh I see. I tried using to_i however I got no method error.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [5, 1, 7 ,8]
arr.join.to_i
```

Comment: 1.9.2-p320 :011 > arr = [5, 1, 7 ,8]
 => [5, 1, 7, 8] 
1.9.2-p320 :012 > arr.join.to_i
 => 5178