# Find the smallest 4-digit number that decreases by 27 when you move its last digit to the first position. (Use the find or detect method) in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run standard ruby training programs, but I had a problem with this program, please take a look. Thank you very much!
Code:

```
q = 9999 #last 4-digit number

while q > 1000                  #from 9999 to 1000, for exemple, the cycle has arrived to 6784

    d = q.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)        #transform 6784 to array [6, 7, 8, 4]

    p = d                   # create sample array with [6, 7, 8, 4]

    tmp = p[0];                 # tmp = 6;

    p[0] = p[3];                # 6 = 4;

    p[3] = tmp;                 # 4 = 6

    g = p.join.to_i             # transform [4, 7, 8, 6] to 4786

    f = q - g               # 6784 - 4786

    if f == 27              # i need to find the smallest 4-digit number that decreases by 27 when moving its last digit to the first position

        puts q              #print 4-digit number that decreases by 27 when moving its last digit to the first position

    end

    q = q - 1; 

end
```

But the result does not appear, it is because it is not, or somewhere a mistake.

In general, the condition of the task is:
Find the smallest 4-digit number that decreases by 27 when you move its last digit to the first position. (Use the find or detect method). Thank You!

Comment: Hey, I've noticed that you didn't accept any answers from your previous questions yet. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (there's no hurry, just don't forget it)

Comment: You are swapping first and last digit. I think you're supposed to move the last digit to the front without changing the remaining digits, i.e. `6784` → `678`|`4` → `4`|`678` → `4678`

Answer (score 2):

I would define a method to "rotate" the number using string manipulation.

```
def rotate_number_one_digit(n)
  s = n.to_s
  "#{s[-1]}#{s[0..-2]}".to_i
end
```

Then I would use `#upto` to deal with the iteration.

```
1000.upto(9999) do |x|

end
```

Each time around you'll check that the "rotated" number plus `27` equals `x`. If so, print it and break the loop to prevent further unnecessary iteration.

```
1000.upto(9999) do |x|
  if rotate_number_one_digit(x) + 27 == x then
    puts x
    break
  end
end
```

Or we can just use the `#find` method from `Enumerable`.

```
1000.upto(9999).find { |x| rotate_number_one_digit(x) + 27 == x }
```

Or using `break` to return a value from the loop.

```
1000.upto(9999) { |x| 
  break x if rotate_number_one_digit(x) + 27 == x 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will first create a helper method to convert an array of digits to an integer.

```
def digits_to_int(arr)
  arr.reduce { |n,d| n*10 + d }
end
```

For example,

```
digits_to_int [1,2,3,4]
  #=> 1234
```

This tends to be faster than `arr.join.to_i` (see sawa's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191938/ruby-convert-array-to-fixnum)).

We can then simply compute

```
(1..).find { |n| n-27 == digits_to_int(n.digits.rotate.reverse) }
  #=> 30
```

See [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a. `inject`), ["Endless range"](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html), [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits), [Array#rotate](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) and [Array#reverse](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse).

---

Here is an example calculation.

```
n = 243
a = n.digits
  #=> [3,4,2]
b = a.rotate
  #=> [4,2,3]
c = b.reverse
  #=> [3,2,4]
d = digits_to_int(c)
  #=> 324
n - 27 == d
  #=> 243 - 27 == 324 => false
```

and another

```
n = 30
a = n.digits
  #=> [0,3]
b = a.rotate
  #=> [3,0]
c = b.reverse
  #=> [0,3]
d = digits_to_int(c)
  #=> 3
n - 27 == d
  #=> 30 - 27 == 3 => true
```